# Apache rewriteCond Rails multi domain setup cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

He People.

I have a rails app running for multiple sites and it has a cache that looks like this:
tmp/cache/adomain.com/the cached files

No this is not picked up by Apache (obviously) and i am trying to set it up 
in my httpd.conf. But I wasn't able to get it working.

This is something i tried:

`< VirtualHost *:80 >

        PassengerMaxPoolSize 20

        PassengerPoolIdleTime 0

        DocumentRoot /mnt/app/current/public

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond  /mnt/app/current/tmp/cache%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} -f

< /VirtualHost>`


But it doesn't seem to work! (of course I restarted apache with: apache2ctl restart)
I googled a lot! but nowhere i did find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're missing a RewriteRule declaration following your RewriteCond.

RewriteCond provides conditional matching of requests, but doesn't take action without a rule to do something.

Probably change to the following, your paths may vary:

```
RewriteCond /mnt/app/current/tmp/cache%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/[^.]+$ /YOUR_CACHE_URI/%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```